# PayPal Orders API payment to a third party payee

Tags: api, paypal

I want to facilitate sending money to a merchant's PayPal account. I've made an additional Business Account in the PayPal Sandbox. I've made an order call with this account as a payee. But when I get the order (after approval from the payer) then the payee is still my actor account. Do I need some special configuration in the sandbox? And in production does the intended payee need to give me special permissions?

```
Array
(
    [intent] => AUTHORIZE
    [application_context] => Array
        (
            [return_url] => http://example.com/cart/PP_Payment.php?success=true
            [cancel_url] => http://example.com/cart/PP_Payment.php?success=false
            [brand_name] => Company X
        )

    [payee] => Array
        (
            [email_address] => sb-u4hosest4@business.example.com
        )

    [inovoice_id] => 1-GD2U-70E7-4Y
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [name] => Rabenhorst Klostergarten BIO Mini
                    [unit_amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 1.04
                        )

                    [sku] => 97899
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [name] => Lupinen Filet
                    [unit_amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 3.87
                        )

                    [sku] => 66911
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [name] => Kühltasche/-akku
                    [unit_amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 6
                        )

                    [sku] => P002
                )

        )

    [purchase_units] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 15.86
                            [breakdown] => Array
                                (
                                    [item_total] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => EUR
                                            [value] => 10.91
                                        )

                                    [shipping] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => EUR
                                            [value] => 4.95
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Result: ##########

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5KPxxxx
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5KPxxxx
                    [rel] => self
                    [method] => GET
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=5KPxxxx
                    [rel] => approve
                    [method] => GET
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5KPxxxx
                    [rel] => update
                    [method] => PATCH
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5KPxxxx/authorize
                    [rel] => authorize
                    [method] => POST
                )

        )

    [status] => CREATED
)
```

but when I get the order then the payee is me and not the selected third party

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5KPxxxx
    [intent] => AUTHORIZE
    [purchase_units] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference_id] => default
                    [amount] => Array
                        (
                            [currency_code] => EUR
                            [value] => 15.86
                            [breakdown] => Array
                                (
                                    [item_total] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => EUR
                                            [value] => 10.91
                                        )

                                    [shipping] => Array
                                        (
                                            [currency_code] => EUR
                                            [value] => 4.95
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [payee] => Array
                        (
                            [email_address] => mike@www.org
                            [merchant_id] => FXXX
                            [display_data] => Array
                                (
                                    [brand_name] => Company X
                                )

                        )

                    [shipping] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [full_name] => test buyer
                                )

                            [address] => Array
                                (
                                    [address_line_1] => ESpachstr. 1
                                    [admin_area_2] => Freiburg
                                    [admin_area_1] => Empty
                                    [postal_code] => 79111
                                    [country_code] => DE
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [payer] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [given_name] => test
                    [surname] => buyer
                )

            [email_address] => mt-buyer@w3xxx.org
            [payer_id] => 4xxx
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [country_code] => DE
                )

        )

    [create_time] => 2020-03-22T09:32:48Z
    [links] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5KPxxxx
                    [rel] => self
                    [method] => GET
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5KPxxxx/authorize
                    [rel] => authorize
                    [method] => POST
                )

        )

    [status] => APPROVED
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [payee] => Array
        (
            [email_address] => sb-u4hosest4@business.example.com
        )
```

This payee is being ignored because it is not in the `purchase_units` object.

See the example in [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/).

---

While you can for sure do intent:CAPTURE, another consideration is that intent:AUTHORIZE (and later capture) might not be supported without permissions.